When embedding Einstein bot in an external site, an error No targetElement specified occurs
When embedding Einstein bot in an external site, an error No targetElement specified occurs because embeddedservice_bootstrap.settings.targetElement is null

How this can be fixed?

The problem was that the script was put into head tag instead of body tag.
Note that here this is mentioned that the script should be placed before the closing body tag.

Once the snippet is placed in the correct place, this attribute is automatically populated with Body tag.

